# Why does it take so long to print "\n" in Perl?

Tags: perl, benchmarking

Why does it take so long to print a newline?  Is this just my machine, or do others see the same effect?

With the newline:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Benchmark;

   timethis(100000,'main();');


   sub main {
      print "you are the bomb. \n";
   }


   # outputs: 
   # timethis 100000:  8 wallclock secs ( 0.15 usr +  0.45 sys =  0.60 CPU) @ 166666.67/s (n=100000)
```

W/o the newline:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Benchmark;

   timethis(100000,'main();');


   sub main {
      print "you are the bomb. ";
   }


   # outputs:
   # timethis 100000:  0 wallclock secs ( 0.09 usr +  0.04 sys =  0.13 CPU) @ 769230.77/s (n=100000)
   #     (warning: too few iterations for a reliable count)
```

> **Edit:** I'd like to add that placing two "\n" causes the execution to take
>   twice as long, at least for wallclock seconds.
>
> ```
> timethis 100000: 16 wallclock secs ( 0.15 usr +  0.52 sys =  0.67 CPU) @ 149253.73/s (n=100000)
> ```

Comment: are you running on windows?  Can you try the same code on linux or mac?  In my experience, writing to the console on windows is a painfully slow procedure, whereas on the other 2 of the Big Three it is very, very fast.

Comment: @rmeador: I'm running on Linux.  I'll be able to do further testing a little later.  I didn't know if this was usual for newlines, or if it was b/c of the setup (OS, terminal, Perl, hardware, etc).

Comment: as the answers have said, the newline is always slow, I was just wondering if you were seeing a completely unexpected slowdown due to Windows having weird console support.

Comment: @rmeador: gotcha - nope, not using Windows.  As mobrule said, the newline isn't always slow, the problem is with the terminal, whether that's buffer-related as others have said, or not.  I guess this would require greater understanding of what's happening in the terminal.  It's hard for me to see that this is a flushing problem when I see the consecutive "you are the bomb."s being printed to screen as they're encountered - there's no delay before they're being printed.

Comment: -1 because u havent updated your question with with your comments.

Comment: @DarthVader: thank you, your abuse of the ranking system has been noted.  Someone has suggested revoking your access to the site, which I said don't do that on my account, but I also said I wouldn't have a problem if you continue to be immature about things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think buffering has much to do with it. I'm guessing it's because the terminal needs to scroll when you print a newline to it (or print enough characters to fill a line). When I benchmark these functions writing to a file or to `/dev/null`, there is not much of a difference.

```
use Benchmark;
timethis(1000000, 'main');
timethis(1000000, 'main2');
select STDERR; $| = 0; select STDOUT;  # enable buffering on STDERR
sub main { print STDERR "you are the bomb. \n" }
sub main2 { print STDERR "you are the bomb. " }

$ perl benchmark.pl 2> a_file
timethis 1000000: 21 wallclock secs ( 4.67 usr + 13.38 sys = 18.05 CPU) @ 55410.87/s
timethis 1000000: 21 wallclock secs ( 4.91 usr + 13.34 sys = 18.25 CPU) @ 54797.52/s

$ perl benchmark.pl 2> /dev/null
timethis 1000000: 26 wallclock secs ( 2.86 usr + 10.36 sys = 13.22 CPU) @ 75648.69/s
timethis 1000000: 27 wallclock secs ( 2.86 usr + 10.30 sys = 13.16 CPU) @ 76010.95/s

$ perl benchmark.pl 2> a_file     (without buffering)
timethis 1000000: 29 wallclock secs ( 3.78 usr + 12.14 sys = 15.92 CPU) @ 62806.18/s
timethis 1000000: 29 wallclock secs ( 3.27 usr + 12.51 sys = 15.78 CPU) @ 63367.34/s

$ perl benchmark.pl 2> /dev/tty   (window has 35 lines and buffers 10000, YMMV)
[ 200000 declarations of how you are a bomb deleted ]
timethis 100000: 53 wallclock secs ( 0.98 usr +  3.73 sys =  4.72 CPU) @ 21190.93/s
timethis 100000:  9 wallclock secs ( 0.36 usr +  1.94 sys =  2.30 CPU) @ 43535.05/s
```

Summary: extra flushing reduces performance by about 10%. Extra scrolling on the terminal reduces performance by about 50%.

Comment: So does that mean any language writing to the console would have a similar performance hit?

Comment: I think this might be the right answer.  As shown by comparing my edit to the first example (two newlines vs one), aside from the wallclock seconds, which is the actual time, the CPU seconds are about the same.  I think the difference can only be deduced to a terminal operation, which I could only assume would be caused by scrolling, or by repositioning the cursor from a newline.

Comment: @justkt, that would be a great addition to the benchmark.  Could you try? :)

Comment: It *does* have to do with buffering.  Terminals are line-buffered (flushing on each \n); redirecting to a file or /dev/null turns this off.

Answer (score 8):

It's not the `\n` per se that causes this problem. Rather, successive calls to `print` are buffered by the OS until the `\n` character is encountered or the buffer is full. At that point, the output buffer is flushed to the screen. Flushing the output to the screen is a (relatively) expensive operation, so the loop in which you flush the output buffer many times has much slower performance than the loop in which you only flush the buffer once at the end (which happens implicitly when your program exits).

Comment: I've also tried turning on the autoflush:
"$|++;" on the second line.  This didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3):

Newline [flushes output](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch07_13.htm).

> In most stdio implementations, buffering varies with the type of output device ... Serial devices, **including terminals**, modems, mice, and joysticks, are normally line-buffered; **stdio sends the entire line out only when it gets the newline**

Comment: The output is to the terminal and is seen as either:
"you are the bomb. 
you are the bomb.
...
you are the bomb.
timethis 100000: # wallclock secs ..."

or 

"you are the bomb.  you are the bomb. ... you are the bomb.  timethis 100000:  # wallclock secs ..."

So all the output is being displayed before the benchmark data.  Does flushing still have an effect on this?  I've only noticed problems with flushing, as like your example says, generally in cgi scripts.

edit: this comment doesn't keep formatting, the 1st example lists the output w/ the newline, the 2nd prints them consecutively.

Comment: Thanks for the addition, but it also says: "Perl's print function does not support truly unbuffered output  - a physical write for each individual character. Instead, it supports command buffering, in which one physical write is made after every separate output command." -- I'd expect every execution of Print to be straight to output, no buffering necessary.